# Which BLE mode to choose, broadcast or connection mode?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

My BLE device sends required data in advertising mode itself. In this case, should I have to still connect? Connection mode seems to disconnect often. Which mode is better?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want. Advertising data is communication in one direction without acknowledgement. When connected you can send data in both directions and you can also encrypt the link.

Comment: Thanks, when using a sniffer, the advertising data seems to provide the information needed. For some reason, the connection mode seems to require more stable input data stream leading to frequent dropping of connection

Comment: "the connection mode seems to require more stable input data stream leading to frequent dropping of connection" if so it seems you have messed something up. Link layer should run independent from the rest of the system if implemented correctly.

Comment: Ok, will look into it. Thanks, Emil.